# Show free space on mapped network drive using hostname instead of IP address on Windows 11

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, network-shares, home-networking

I'm trying to understand why and if possible correct the fact that upon connecting and mapping a network drive on Windows 11 said drive reports numerically the free space remaining on only if connected through its IP address. If instead I use its hostname (given out by my Fritzbox router) it mounts and maps with no problems and it even shows the bar displaying graphically how much free space it still has but it doesn't display the numeric amount near the shared drive name. If I go into its properties I can see it no problem so it's not a problem of data not being passed through for some reason.

Is it possible to correct this behaviour or is it a limitation of Windows 11?

[What I get vs what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAgws.png)

Comment: Try restarting the explorer.exe process in task manager

Comment: @mully no dice unfortunately. Not even restarting Windows.

Comment: Odd issue that I had with Windows 10, might be the same for 11, but sometimes if the network path is too long, you won't see the disk usage, try shortening the path...

Comment: Following up on what mully said ... can you test it out by giving it a shorter name? The name "raspberry4.fritz.box" is long enough that it wraps the "(Z:)" to the next line, and then the bar to the third line, leaving no room for the numerical report of the free space. If you could create a DNS entry of, say, "r4.fritz.box", and map to it that way, that should allow the letter indication to stay on the first line, and that might bring back the numeric info.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @DougDeden, I tried your solution but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is Windows have the concept of **Network Location** vs. **Mapped Drive**.

> **Network Location:** is a shared storage device that can be accessed by two or more computers on the same network

> **Mapped Drive:** is a network drive assigned a drive letter in Windows

Try using the instruction [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d) to map it as a drive using the hostname.

**Reference:**

- [Explaining Network Drives and Mapped Drives](https://iboysoft.com/wiki/network-drive.html#:%7E:text=A%20network%20drive%20is%20a,a%20mount%20point%20in%20macOS.)
- [Network share size/available space not showing in windows explorer](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1154200-network-share-sizeavailable-space-not-showing-in-windows-explorer/)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't help. As I said it's a mapped drive, not a location.

Adding a screenshot to better exemplify my issue.